# Sending True/False from python api call

Tags: javascript, python

i dont know if this is a stupid question but ive made a script that is making a api put call using requests in python. The data im trying to send contains a boolean value. So i have my script like this

```
import requests

data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'lastname': "Doe",
    'email': "jd@gmail.com",
    'is_staff' : True
}

url = 'http://api.url/user/'
response = requests.put(
    url, data=data, verify=True, allow_redirects=False)

print(response)
```

But this gives me a 400 request error.
Then i thought that the problem was with the api call but when i remove the is_staff data.

```
data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'lastname': "Doe",
    'email': "jd@gmail.com",
}
```

I get a 200 status code. My inutution is telling me that the api doesnt know what the boolean value from python is. But i could be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to JSON encode your string or rather 'serialize'.

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table. If ensure_ascii is false, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value may be a unicode instance.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
import requests
import json

data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'lastname': "Doe",
    'email': "jd@gmail.com",
    'is_staff' : True
}

url = 'http://api.url/user/'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=True, allow_redirects=False)

print(response)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -2):

The requests library takes the data dict and turns it into the request body, the request body is not a dict but a string containing the keys and values. In this case it turns it into the key1=value1&key2=value2 form.

You can view the request body the requests library is sending by:

```
response.request.body
```

It returns

```
'name=John&lastname=Doe&email=jd%40gmail.com&is_staff=True'
```

In this case the boolean you are sending is turned into "True" or "False". The problem could be that the webserver is expecting a "true" or "false" instead but it depends on the server.
Try:

```
data = {
    'name': 'John',
    'lastname': "Doe",
    'email': "jd@gmail.com",
    'is_staff' : "true"
}
```

Or the dynamic:

```
is_staff = True
data = {
    'name': "John",
    'lastname': "Doe",
    'email': "jd@gmail.com",
    'is_staff' : str(is_staff).lower()
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation but this doesn't change anything because 'true' will still be sent as string type in the request and not bool type